# Python Requests and Bonanza API Node.js / Unable to Properly Make API Requests / No Node.js Documentation

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-3.x, python-requests

I am following the [Bonanza.com Bonapitit documentation](https://api.bonanza.com/docs/reference/fetch_token) and successfully got their Python fetchToken script to work. However, I am now trying to recreate this same script in Node.js because I want it in my ExpressJS backend (and not Python).

Here is what the working fetchToken Python script looks like...

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.bonanza.com/api_requests/secure_request'

# See your Bonapitit welcome e-mail or your Bonapitit dashboard for
# your developer and certificate identifiers
headers = {
    'X-BONANZLE-API-DEV-NAME' : 'my_dev_name',
    'X-BONANZLE-API-CERT-NAME' : 'my_cert_name'
}

request_name = 'fetchTokenRequest'

# make the request to Bonanza
response = requests.post(url, data=request_name, headers=headers)

# the json response as a dictionary
response_json = response.json()

# examine the response
if response_json['ack'] == 'Success' and 'fetchTokenResponse' in response_json:
    token_response = response_json['fetchTokenResponse']

    print("Your token: " + token_response['authToken'])
    print("Token expiration time: " + token_response['hardExpirationTime'])
    print("Authentication URL: " + token_response['authenticationURL'])
else:
    print(response_json)
```

So I thought, ok, this should be easy enough to convert over to JavaScript, so here is what I tried...

```
exports.fetchToken = async (req, res) => {
  let _id = req.params.userId
  let bonanza_devId
  let bonanza_certId
  try {
    let user = await User.findById({_id})
    bonanza_devId = user.bonanza_devId
    bonanza_certId = user.bonanza_certId
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Got an error when obtaining the user data in fetchToken...`, e)
  }
  try {
    let request_name = 'fetchTokenRequest'
    let headers = {
      'X-BONANZLE-API-DEV-NAME' : bonanza_devId,
      'X-BONANZLE-API-CERT-NAME' : bonanza_certId,
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      request_name: request_name
  }
    let url = `https://api.bonanza.com/api_requests/secure_request`
    let response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: headers,
      body: new URLSearchParams({
        request_name
      })
    })
    response = await response.json()
    res.json(response)
  } catch (e) {
    res.json({error: e})
  }
}
```

(the above script is fetching a user from the database, getting the api creds from that, then attempting to make the call)

Unfortunately I am getting this error when using the JavaScript version...

```
{
    "ack": "Failure",
    "version": "1.1.2",
    "timestamp": "2021-06-19T18:53:00.000Z",
    "errorMessage": {
        "message": "The request was not formatted correctly",
        "type": "Bonapitit::InvalidRequestFormat"
    }
}
```

I think `request_name = 'fetchTokenRequest'` is not being put into the script wrongly because in the Python script it is using `data=request_name`.

What is the equivalent in JavaScript fetch to `data=request_name?

Also, when I tried to change the Content-Type from `"Content-Type": "application/json"` to `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`, it changes the error message to this...

```
{
    "ack": "Failure",
    "version": "1.1.2",
    "timestamp": "2021-06-19T19:04:54.000Z",
    "errorMessage": {
        "message": "Bonapitit::CannotFindRequest",
        "type": "Bonapitit::CannotFindRequest"
    }
}
```

In the documentation, it states `The name for your request should be fetchTokenRequest.`  How are you supposed to "name your request" like that?

If you can spot the issue in my script, please respond.

Comment: Using `data` in `requests` sets the content type to `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`. The data itself is the whole body of the request (URL encoded). So in your JS script you just need to pass the string `"fetchTokenRequest"` as the body (url encoded)

Comment: @rdas I love you!  This completely solved it for me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @rdas, I solved it in the following way...

```
let headers = {
      'X-BONANZLE-API-DEV-NAME' : bonanza_devId,
      'X-BONANZLE-API-CERT-NAME' : bonanza_certId,
      Accept: "application/json",
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
  }
let url = `https://api.bonanza.com/api_requests/secure_request`
let response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: headers,
      body: encodeURIComponent("fetchTokenRequest")
    })
```

With this I successfully obtained the token.

This made all the difference...
`encodeURIComponent("fetchTokenRequest")`

I suspect all their API calls can be made in NodeJS this way.